# Magento 2: Disable cache for price block

Tags: magento2, price, frontend, cache

I want to disable the cache of the price block in detail page. However, I cannot find a place to modify it. I try to add `cacheable="false"` in

> module-catalog\view\base\layout\catalog_product_prices.xml

but it is still not working. Also, I try to override the class

> module-catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox.php

with

```
protected function getCacheLifetime()
{
    return null;
}
```

and it also cannot disable the cache.

Please help.

Comment: you can do that using XML block

Comment: Why do you need to disable it? Can you give us more info?

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I am looking for several solutions.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143377)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143377)